# Building and debugging a program with makefile

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile

As part of my university studies I learn C programming. I'm using Eclipse Juno IDE.

Here is the problem: I have few .c and .h files, and a makefile made by our course staff. I want to build the project with this makefile. I spent hours searching all over the internet how to build and debug it, but everytime I think I got it an error jumps.

Can someone **please** explain once and for always how to do this process - build the project with the given makefile, and run it in debug mode so I can debug it?

---

It is important to mention that sometimes I failed to build the project and got the following message:

```
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file Assignment2altVersion.exe: Permission denied
```

However, I managed to build the project several times, but when I tried to run it in debug mode it was stuck either on "Launching: Configuring GDB" or "Launching C/C++ Application".

EDIT:
there are 6 files: SP_Stack.c, SP_Stack.h, SP_Aux.c, SP_Aux., SP_Stack_UnitTest.c, main.c

SP_Aux.c and main.c #include SP_Aux.h.
SP_Stack.c, SP_Aux. and SP_Stack_UnitTest.c #include SP_Stack.h

here's the makefile:

```
ex2: main.o SP_Aux.o SP_Stack.o
    gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors  main.o SP_Aux.o SP_Stack.o -o ex2

Stack_UnitTest: SP_Stack.o SP_Stack_UnitTest.o
    gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors  SP_Stack.o SP_Stack_UnitTest.o -o Stack_UnitTest

main.o: main.c SP_Aux.h SP_Stack.h
    gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors -c main.c 

SP_Stack.o: SP_Stack.c SP_Stack.h
    gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors -c SP_Stack.c

SP_Stack_UnitTest.o: SP_Stack.h SP_Stack_UnitTest.c
    gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors -c SP_Stack_UnitTest.c

SP_Aux.o: SP_Aux.c SP_Aux.h
    gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors -c SP_Aux.c

clean:
    rm -f main.o SP_Aux.o SP_Stack.o SP_Stack_UnitTest.o Stack_UnitTest ex2
```

the 6 files I mentioned and the makefile are all in the same directory.
I just tried it all over again: went to the right side of the screen to the "make targets" tab. I chose my project and created a target named "makefile" with "make" as build command. then I double clicked it and the project finishe building. when I tried to run it in debug mode it gets stuck on 96% with a message: "Launching: configuring GDB"

Comment: `Permission denied` can appear in Windows if your program is running at build moment

Comment: I know that, however when I look in Task Manager I don't see the program running...

Comment: the `permission denied` can be output when the make file tries to write to a file or directory that it does not have the appropriate permissions to change

Comment: Post the makefiile.  Post the layout of your source and header files. Indicate which directory in that layout  is where the makefile is being executed.  Post the command line being used to run the makefile.   Post the actual error message, not just an excerpt from that message.  Until the details are posted, there is not much of anything we can do but guess.

Comment: @user3629249 Done. hope it's easier to understand now.

Comment: the make file seems to be missing this at top of file: `.PHONY: all clean` then `all: ex2  Stack_UnitTest`

Comment: when using `gcc` to compile, be sure it produces the debug info.  I.E.  include the `-g` parameter to EVERY call to gcc for both compile and link steps.   Note: if going to use `gdb` for debugging, (suggest running `gdb` outside the IDE)  then change the suggested `-g` parameter to `-ggdb` so `gcc` will output the maximum debug info.

Comment: the error message seems to indicate that all the compile/link worked correctly, then the IDE could not find the `gdb` debugger.

Comment: usually both `gcc` and `gdb` are in the same directory (on linux: /usr/bin) Therefore, the first thing I would do is assure that 1) the `PATH` environment variable includes the `/user/bin` directory 2) assure the IDE setup includes the path to the `gdb` debugger